# How to fetch all sites and subsites which are accessible to sharepoint user?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

I am working on project where I need to read data from the SharePoint site.

My client application will take login credentials as input. How can I get all sites which can be accessed by the provided user?

Here is the sample code:

```
 string url = "https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com";

 SecureString f_SecurePass = new SecureString();
 foreach(char ch in pass)
 f_SecurePass.AppendChar(ch);

 clientcontext = new ClientContext(url);

 var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userid, f_SecurePass);

 clientcontext.Credentials = credentials;

 Web _website = clientcontext.Web;
 clientcontext.Load(_website, website => website.Webs, website => website.Title);
 clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();

 //_website.Webs contains no entries. where as on sharepoint
 // I have created multiple sites

 foreach(Web _web in _website.Webs) {
     string newpath = url + _web.ServerRelativeUrl;

     Console.WriteLine(newpath + "\n" + _web.Title);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to iterate the sites/subsites and check user permissions by
Web.GetUserEffectivePermissions

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getusereffectivepermissions.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: The user is not admin. So I can't fetch all sites from sharepoint. Please help